# get the number of drawcalls in android unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine

is it possible to calculate draw calls programatically in unity3d?

i know we can check draw calls using Rendering Stats in Windows editor, but want to check the same on Android/iOS device.

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the frame debug on your device, it will show each draw call done on it.

[image: Running an app on my phone]

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you build a frame counter? 
http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=FramesPerSecond
With a custom made frame counter you can get the draw calls no matter the platform.

Comment: draw calls are different to frame time (never measure FPS! http://www.mvps.org/directx/articles/fps_versus_frame_time.htm), and none of the widgets in your link measure draw calls.